# Showing class attributes in the PyCharm debugger when subclassing str

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I want to see class attributes for a subclass of `str` in the debugger.

[image: Example image]

Refer to the picture - I want to have the dropdown arrow next to `a` (which is a `POSString` object). In other words, in the Pycharm debugger I want to have the option to doubleclick `a` and see the attribute `bar` with value `"HELLO"`, exactly like for the `foo` object.

Is this possible in PyCharm, and if yes how?

The two classes:

```py
class Foo:
    bar = "HELLO"


class POSString(str):
    bar = "HELLO"

    def __init__(self, pos="", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pos = pos

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((str(self), self.pos))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return super().__eq__(other) and self.pos == other.pos
```

And how I create my two objects:

```py
foo = Foo()
a = POSString("banana")
```

I am using Python 3.7.1.

PyCharm:

```
PyCharm 2018.2.5 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-182.5107.22, built on November 13, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b22 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
```

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm doesn't currently have a setting to configure display in the [Variables Tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html#tabs) of the Debug tool window with that detail. The IDE takes most display decision automatically based on the type of the object. The only option currently available is sorting values inside a single variable using the setting at `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Build, Execution, Deployment` `>` `Debugger` `>` `Data Views` `>` `Sort values alphabetically`. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525307) for a more detailed explanation).

This can be inconvenient for purpose of debugging, the example `class` in the question is displayed exactly like a string because the class inherits from string. That's an IDE decision and there's currently no way to change it (apart from posting a feature request with [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)).

The alternatives are setting "Watches" in the Variables Tab or using the Console. The other more inconvenient alternative is changing the class itself to not inherit from string (in which case it will be displayed like regular classes are) however this can break any number of functionalities in your code, so the debugging convenience gained can be outweighed by the inconveniences caused.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign a variable with the POSString objects `__dict__` attribute:

```
a = POSString('HELLO')
_a = a.__dict__
```

Then you can access all the attributes of `a` through `_a`.

Other way around is not to inherit from `str`, add the `str` to an attribute and override the `__getattribute__` method to forward calls to the `str` object.

```
class POSString():
    bar = "HELLO"

    def __init__(self, pos="", *args, **kwargs):
        #super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.str = str(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pos = pos

    def __hash__(self):
        #return hash((str(self), self.pos))
        return hash((self.str, self.pos)) 

    def __eq__(self, other):
        #return super().__eq__(other) and self.pos == other.pos
        return self.str.__eq__(other) and self.pos == other.pos  

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.str, attr)
```

I think, after all, that is not good practice to inherit from `str`

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake, I already fixed it

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because it will break dependencies of the string type where your code uses the original `POSString` from the question. So it's not a solution unless the new object defined [the full interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) of `str` which is inherited by the original. For example `isinstance(POSString, str)` is `True` for the original but `False` for your implementation. I mention this in the linked post in my answer. So it would still be simpler to set the variable watches for what you need in the IDE than changing the code.

Comment: The only ideal solution is for JetBrains to implement a new display for this case in the Variables Tab of PyCharm.